# PayPal REST SDK Error 500

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a site making calls to the PayPal sandbox. This has worked fine in the past. Today, all of my calls are returning INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.  I am using the Node.js paypal-rest-sdk module to make these calls.

The debug ID of the transactions are 38ddafc521580, bc93a6d0f3b60, and fb3f7b74697c9.

On a related note - I don't see anywhere on PayPal developer support where you can directly ask for help with these issues; PayPal seems to just point to StackOverflow.  Is that correct? Seems like I should just be able to log into the PayPal developer portal and ask for help with specific debug IDs, or at least see some more detail for those transactions on why they failed.  Using StackOverflow for this doesn't feel "right" to me...

Comment: I'm also having this problem with the .NET SDK. Some of my debug IDs include `3b6c59992c75f`, `23c9d9f36760d`, and `d87754302e4a5`.

Comment: Same issue with the Python SDK.

Comment: Same issue with PHP PayPal Rest.

Comment: Just posted an update below - can you please test again?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: An update was pushed out just now that should resolve most of the external issues. Can you all please let me know if you are still seeing problems? There are a few outstanding problems in the cleanup, so I want to make sure they aren't impacting anything.

Full disclosure: I work at PayPal

I just ran a test against sandbox and have confirmed that there appears to be some downtime. I've notified the sandbox team of the problem and have provided your (and my) debug ids for them to take a look. We're on it and will hopefully have a resolution shortly.

From the support side, you're correct, there is no forum system for technical integration issues. For problems with downtime, you can report those to the technical support team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ1OTM0NzAxNi9zaWQvVC00anZNTW0%3D, or contact support directly from https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/home. You can always reach out to the merchant technical support Twitter handle at https://twitter.com/paypal_mts as well.

For integration troubles, that's where SO would be best, where we can help work through code issues.

Answer (score 0):

The server errors have gone away, but they've been accompanied by a massive uptick in customers getting a message that reads "the card you entered cannot be used for this payment". So they're still not able to make payments. We had the first couple contact PayPal, but we've gotten so many that it seems like it's not a coincidence. Do we really need to refer people to PayPal (which will cause them grief, surely, and cause PayPal to get a bunch of extra calls) or is there still something going on?